# Using a list on a query condition in Erlang

Tags: postgresql, list, erlang

I've got the `Variable1` which consists of a list: `[1, 5]`
I'm trying to prepare a statement that reads as follows:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM tab_name WHERE field1 = Variable1
```

But this only works if Variable1 has only 1 value. If it has more (e.g. 1 and 5), I get an error.

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Could you give as a more complete example as well as the error message?

Comment: What kind of query is that?

Comment: It's an Erlang statement, so I can access a postgresql Database table. I know it's just a question of syntax.

Comment: The correct syntax has nothing to do with Erlang, more to do with SQL. When you have a list of things to query on, you need to use `in (...)` or a bunch of `or` statements. In your Erlang code, check for the type and length for `Variable1`, so you can build the correct query string.